# How to collect and view prices in the Experience Profile Commerce tab in another currency?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

In the Experience Profile Commerce tab the prices are shown in USD even though I all currencies in EUR.

I like to collect and view the prices in EUR in the Experience Profile. How is that possible?

As an example I called *Sitecore.Commerce.Services.Catalog.CatalogServiceProvider.VisitedProductDetailsPage* with a request with the currency EUR but the price shown in "Products viewed" is still in USD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change currency for **Experience Profile reports** you need to patch `Commerce.ExperienceProfile.ReportingCurrencyCode` setting:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Commerce.ExperienceProfile.ReportingCurrencyCode" set:value="EUR"/>
      </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

If you want to change currency for **Experience Analytics reports** you need to patch `Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics.ReportingCurrencyCode` setting:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics.ReportingCurrencyCode" set:value="EUR"/>
      </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

[image]